# Reviewing a Canvas Drawing Utility in plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, html, css

So for a class project, I have to figure out the most efficient way to draw on a canvas.

First thing that came to mind was using moveTo and lineTo repeatedly following mouse cursor, and thats exactly what I did.

I also added a strange "liner" pen which draws lines outwards from a point (side effect of bug, which I then turned into a tool)

Furthermore I added a coloring and sizing option, so you can be creative with it.

Sizing option, Spray tool, and Color Options are all non-functional rn.

I'm not really sure how to get the color or sizing option working if anyone wants to take a crack at it.

**I want to know if anyone sees any bad practice uses that I have created, or has any improvements/tips that I should keep in mind as I continue development on the canvas.**

**Also the GUI and Buttons and everything, its all temporary, my main job is to actually finish the project.**

https://repl.it/@skylerspark/Dynamic-Drawing-Utility-DDU

Heres the live development version, and heres the current version as of posting this code review:

```js
const query = document.querySelector.bind(document);

// Config
let curLine = [0, 0],
  curColor = "#000000",
  curSize = 2;

// Cursor Coords
function drawingBoardGetMouse(cvs, e) {
  let rect = cvs.getBoundingClientRect(),
    scaleX = cvs.width / rect.width,
    scaleY = cvs.height / rect.height;
  return {
    x: (e.clientX - rect.left) * scaleX,
    y: (e.clientY - rect.top) * scaleY
  };
}

// Dynamic Drawing Utility (DDU)
class drawingBoard {
  constructor(canvas) {
    // Generate a dynamic canvas selector, or manually select it yourself via the main args
    this.cvs = canvas || document.querySelector("canvas");
    this.ctx = this.cvs.getContext("2d");

    this.cvs.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
      let m = drawingBoardGetMouse(this.cvs, e);
      curLine = [m.x, m.y];
      this.mouseDown = true;
    });

    this.cvs.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
      this.mouseDown = false;
    });

    this.cvs.addEventListener("mousemove", this.onMouseMove.bind(this));
  }
  draw(e) { // Free Draw Pen
    let m = drawingBoardGetMouse(this.cvs, e);
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.fillStyle = curColor;
    this.ctx.lineWidth = curSize;
    this.ctx.moveTo(curLine[0], curLine[1]);
    this.ctx.lineTo(m.x, m.y);
    this.ctx.stroke();
    curLine = [m.x, m.y];
  }
  draw2(e) { // Line Draw Pen
    let m = drawingBoardGetMouse(this.cvs, e);
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.fillStyle = curColor;
    this.ctx.lineWidth = curSize;
    this.ctx.moveTo(curLine[0], curLine[1]);
    this.ctx.lineTo(m.x, m.y);
    this.ctx.stroke();
  }
  onMouseMove(event) { // Detect movement
    if (!this.mouseDown) {
      return; // If mouse isnt held down, dont draw
    }
    if (this.drawingMode == 1) {
      return this.draw(event); // Free-draw
    } else if (this.drawingMode == 2) {
      return this.draw2(event); // Line-draw
    } else if (this.drawingMode == 3) {
      return this.draw3(event); // Spray-draw
    }
  }
  dragAndDraw() {
    this.drawingMode = 1;
  }
  dragAndLine() {
    this.drawingMode = 2;
  }
  dragAndSpray() {
    this.drawingMode = 3;
  }
}

// API Usage

const draw = new drawingBoard(); // Initialize new board

query(".color").addEventListener("input", e => {
  curColor = e.target.value;
});

query(".drawer").addEventListener("click", () => {
  draw.dragAndDraw();
});

query(".liner").addEventListener("click", () => {
  draw.dragAndLine();
});

query(".sprayer").addEventListener("click", () => {
  draw.dragAndSpray();
});
```

```css
* {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.canvas {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.buttons {
  display: inline-block;
}

button,
input {
  width: 8em;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-left: -2px;
}

input {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<div class="buttons">
  <input type="color" class="color"><br>
  <input type="text" class="size" placeholder="Size"><br>
  <button class="drawer">Free Draw</button><br>
  <button class="liner">Line Draw</button><br>
  <button class="sprayer">Spray Draw</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, draw and draw2 looks pretty similar to me, you can DRY them

```js
class drawingBoard {

    // ...

    draw (e) {
        this.draw2(e)
        let m = drawingBoardGetMouse(this.cvs, e)
        curLine = [m.x, m.y]
    }
    draw2 (e) {
        let m = drawingBoardGetMouse(this.cvs, e)
        this.ctx.beginPath()
        this.ctx.fillStyle = curColor
        this.ctx.lineWidth = curSize
        this.ctx.moveTo(curLine[0], curLine[1])
        this.ctx.lineTo(m.x, m.y)
        this.ctx.stroke()
    }

    // ...

}
```

Then, there is a "not so useful" if statement

```js
if (this.drawingMode == 1) {
    return this.draw(event) // Free-draw
} else if (this.drawingMode == 2) {
    return this.draw2(event) // Line-draw
} else if (this.drawingMode == 3) {
    return this.draw3(event) // Spray-draw
}
```

Here is how you can replace it, which will improve the readability and elegance of the code

```js
// ...

class drawingBoard {

    // ...

    onMouseMove (event) {
        if (!this.mouseDown) {
            return // If mouse isnt held down, dont draw
        }
        if (this.drawingMode in this) {
            this[this.drawingMode](event)
        }
    }

    dragAndDraw (e) {
        this.dragAndLine(e)
        let m = drawingBoardGetMouse(this.cvs, e)
        curLine = [m.x, m.y]
    }

    dragAndLine (e) {
        let m = drawingBoardGetMouse(this.cvs, e)
        this.ctx.beginPath()
        this.ctx.fillStyle = curColor
        this.ctx.lineWidth = curSize
        this.ctx.moveTo(curLine[0], curLine[1])
        this.ctx.lineTo(m.x, m.y)
        this.ctx.stroke()
    }

    dragAndSpray () {
        // TODO ?
    }
}


// ...


query('.drawer').addEventListener('click', () => {
    draw.drawingMode = 'dragAndDraw'
})

query('.liner').addEventListener('click', () => {
    draw.drawingMode = 'dragAndLine'
})

query('.sprayer').addEventListener('click', () => {
    draw.drawingMode = 'dragAndSpray'
})
```

You can move the global variables into instance variables so you can create multiple instances of drawingBoard if you want

```js
class drawingBoard {

    constructor (canvas) {

        // ...

        this.curLine = [0, 0]
        this.curColor = '#000000'
        this.curSize = 2


        this.cvs.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
            let m = drawingBoardGetMouse(this.cvs, e)
            this.curLine = [m.x, m.y]
            this.mouseDown = true
        })

        // ...
        
    }

    dragAndDraw (e) {
        this.dragAndLine(e)
        this.curLine = [m.x, m.y]
    }
    
    dragAndLine (e) {
        // ...

        this.ctx.fillStyle = this.curColor
        this.ctx.lineWidth = this.curSize
        this.ctx.moveTo(this.curLine[0], this.curLine[1])

        // ...
    }
    
}
```

---

Here is my final take with some flavor adjustments

```js
class DrawingBoard {

    constructor (canvas) {

        this.canvas  = canvas || document.querySelector('canvas')
        this.ctx     = this.canvas.getContext('2d')

        this.currentLine = {x: 0, y: 0}
        this.color       = '#000000'
        this.size        = 2

        registerMouseEvents(this)
    }

    draw (mouseEvent) {
        if (!this.mouseDown) {
            return
        }

        if (this.drawingMode in this) {
            this[this.drawingMode](mouseEvent)
        }
    }

    dragAndDraw (e) {
        this.dragAndLine(e)
        this.currentLine = getMouseCoords(this.canvas, e)
    }

    dragAndLine (e) {
        let coords = getMouseCoords(this.canvas, e)
        this.ctx.beginPath()
        this.ctx.fillStyle = this.color
        this.ctx.lineWidth = this.size
        this.ctx.moveTo(this.currentLine.x, this.currentLine.y)
        this.ctx.lineTo(coords.x, coords.y)
        this.ctx.stroke()
    }

    dragAndSpray () {
        // TODO ?
    }
}



function registerMouseEvents (drawingBoard) {

    const canvas = drawingBoard.canvas

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
        drawingBoard.currentLine = getMouseCoords(canvas, e)
        drawingBoard.mouseDown = true
    })

    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
        drawingBoard.mouseDown = false
    })

    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
        drawingBoard.draw(e)
    })

}



function getMouseCoords (canvas, e) {

    let rect   = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
    let scaleX = canvas.width  / rect.width
    let scaleY = canvas.height / rect.height

    return {
        x: (e.clientX - rect.left) * scaleX,
        y: (e.clientY - rect.top)  * scaleY
    }

}



// USAGE

const query = document.querySelector.bind(document)
const drawingBoard = new DrawingBoard()


query('.color').addEventListener('input', e => {
    drawingBoard.color = e.target.value
})

query('.drawer').addEventListener('click', () => {
    drawingBoard.drawingMode = 'dragAndDraw'
})

query('.liner').addEventListener('click', () => {
    drawingBoard.drawingMode = 'dragAndLine'
})

query('.sprayer').addEventListener('click', () => {
    drawingBoard.drawingMode = 'dragAndSpray'
})
```

```css
* {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.canvas {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.buttons {
  display: inline-block;
}

button,
input {
  width: 8em;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-left: -2px;
}

input {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<div class="buttons">
  <input type="color" class="color"><br>
  <input type="text" class="size" placeholder="Size"><br>
  <button class="drawer">Free Draw</button><br>
  <button class="liner">Line Draw</button><br>
  <button class="sprayer">Spray Draw</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou! This is very informing, I didnt realise some of these issues up front, thanks a ton!